# Looping Through a dictionary with custom object items

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure I'm missing the huge elephant in the room but I keep getting errors on this. I'm creating a public dictionary called `Prompts` and filling it with a custom class object in the sub below.

```
Public Sub SetPromptControls()
Dim PromptsRange As Range
Dim PromptRow As Range

Set PromptsRange = Range("LookUpTablePrompts")
Dim NewPrompt As clsPrompt
For Each PromptRow In PromptsRange.Rows
    Set NewPrompt = New clsPrompt
    NewPrompt.Name = PromptRow.Cells(1, 1)
    NewPrompt.ControlType = PromptRow.Cells(1, 2)
    NewPrompt.ComboboxValues = PromptRow.Cells(1, 3)
    NewPrompt.HelpText = PromptRow.Cells(1, 4)
    NewPrompt.TabIndex = PromptRow.Cells(1, 5)
    NewPrompt.ColumnIndex = PromptRow.Cells(1, 6)
    NewPrompt.TableIndex = PromptRow.Cells(1, 7)
    NewPrompt.ControlName = PromptRow.Cells(1, 8)


    Me.Prompts.Add NewPrompt.ControlName, NewPrompt
Next
End Sub
```

Now I'm trying to loop through the dictionary I just made in this next sub which is inside the same class. The problem is the for each loop keeps giving me object errors

```
Public Sub SetProductPromptMapping()
Dim ProductPromptMappingRange As Range
Dim SKURange As Range
Dim SKUPromptMapRow As Integer
Dim MapRow As Range
Dim Key As Variant
Dim Prompt As clsPrompt
Set ProductPromptMappingRange = Range("LookUpTablePromptMap")
Set SKURange = ProductPromptMappingRange.Find(PromptsForm.SKU, LookIn:=xlValues)
SKUPromptMapRow = SKURange.Row - 2

For Each Key In Prompts.Keys
    Set Prompt = New clsPrompt
    Prompt = Key
    Me.ProductPromptMappingRow.Add Prompt.ControlName, ProductPromptMappingRange.Cells(SKUPromptMapRow, Prompt.TableIndex).Value
Next

End Sub
```

Ultimately I would like to loop through my `Prompts` dictionary and cast the current item back to my `clsPrompt` class object so that I can access its properties.

Comment: `Set Prompt = Prompts(Key)` and remove the `Prompt = Key` line should do it.

Answer (score 6):

As [Comintern correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399150/looping-through-a-dictionary-with-custom-object-items#comment66124382_39399150), you've been bit by a common mistake - trying to assign an object reference without the `Set` keyword. Here's the smallest example I can come up with that demonstrates the problem:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim foo As MyClass
    foo = New MyClass
End Sub
```

Here there's a local `foo` object variable that's assigned a reference (`= New MyClass`), but because the assignment is made without the `Set` keyword, running this would raise a runtime error 91:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Your code has that exact same issue:

```
Dim Prompt As clsPrompt
'...
'more code
'...
Prompt = Key
```

The code happily *compiles*, but will consistently raise that runtime error 91 when *executed*.

This mistake is common enough (just look at [how many questions involve runtime error 91](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+is%3Aquestion+%2291%22) right here on Stack Overflow), that I've decided to implement an inspection for it in the latest version of [**Rubberduck**](http://rubberduckvba.com), an open-source COM add-in for the VBE that can help you clean up your code (I'm managing the project):

[image: Rubberduck code inspections]

> **Object variable 'foo' is assigned without the 'Set' keyword**
>
> As far as Rubberduck can tell, this variable is an object variable, assigned without the 'Set' keyword. This causes run-time error 91 'Object or With block variable not set'.

Rubberduck would have caught that error =)

---

What it *wouldn't* have caught though, is that it doesn't make much sense to assign `Prompt` a new reference, just to re-assign it to some `Variant` right away. Again as [Comintern correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399150/looping-through-a-dictionary-with-custom-object-items#comment66124382_39399150), you need to `Set Prompt = Prompts(Key)` here.

Comment: I really enjoy reading your answers, because you do it in a very detailed and didactic way. I don't have nothing useful to add here, but I'd just like to point out that you have a little typo in your very last sentence. `Propmts(Key)` should be `Prompts(Key)`